# Do you want me continuing?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this phrase correct?

> Do you want me continuing?

I usually use that phrase to ask my boss if he needs more support from me in a specific activity. But obviously I'm not quite sure if it's the correct way.

Comment: "Do you still need my help?" works for me. "Do you want me continuing" sounds unwieldy.

Comment: "Do you want me to continue"  would be more correct, but I don't have the skill to explain the techical details of why.

Comment: @Jasen It's just because *want* is followed by an -*ing* form of the verb. However, I'd like to know if it makes sense to say *want me continuining* for a native speaker. Is it grammatically correct? I think it could be idiomatic but not grammatical.

Comment: @Ustanak: You've got that completely the wrong way round! *Do you want me continuing?* is perfectly grammatical, but totally non-idiomatic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My god haha. Why is that?

Comment: @Ustanak: The easy answer would just be "Idiomatic usages don't have *reasons*". But if I'm honest I suspect there *is* a reason in this case - I just don't know what it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead say:

> Do you need anything else?
>
> Do you need any more help?
>
> Is there anything else I can do?

If I was going to make the sentence in your title sound more natural, I would write:

> Do you want me to continue?

This, however, sounds is just a bit *too much*. I can't quite say why, but it sounds a bit snarky to me.

Comment: I've heard people saying *do you want me to stop?* — Is that construction weird for a native speaker?

Comment: That construction is fine, but it doesn't quite match the situation you described in your question. I wouldn't ask *do you want me to stop?* unless the person I was talking was acting visibly uncomfortable or unhappy with what I was saying.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the phrase construction, it would have to be:

> Do you want me to continue?

There are more than one reason for it.

- 1st: After the verb **want**, you have to use the following verb only in its infinite form, besides, and
- 2nd: after the verb **want** you have a personal pronoun.

Furthermore, let´s take the verb **suggest** as an example: After the verb **suggest** you must use the following verb with the *-ing* ending, however, if you say for example:

> I suggest you eat some of this food, it is delicious!

Although the verb **eat** has to go without **to**, you cannot use use **eating** because there is a personal pronoun before the following verb.